# Can my question please be reopened?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-closed

This one: [How to show a banner using a Chrome extension which doesn't require DOM modification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34939666/in-chrome-extension-how-to-create-a-warning-message-displayed-next-to-the-page)

I edited and updated the content. I think it is much clearer now.

Comment: That's still too broad in my view, *"how can I...?"* questions are not a good fit for SO's model.

Comment: I've moved to camp 4, so sure! +1 and voted to reopen.

Comment: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260)

Comment: That was edited by others.

Comment: I still think that question is overly broad but if you bring in the chrome.infobar background info that was provided in the comments, preferable by adding a code sample if possible it would fly better. I casted the last re-open vote that was needed but that isn't a guarantee it stays open now.

Comment: This question is a "request to have a specific question reopened by the community" so it definitely is about Stack Overflow. Voted to reopen (this Meta question).

Comment: @Tunaki What are you quoting from?

Comment: @BilltheLizard The wiki of the [meta-tag:reopen-closed] tag.

Comment: Your question is too broad. It needs to be more narrow, [like this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12769982/1842065).

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå I hope that is sarcasm.... is sarcasm right?

Comment: @Braiam If you're referring to my last comment then yes, it's sarcasm ;)

Comment: I really have no idea if the question under discussion is too broad or not, but I get the feeling that some users are simply reacting negatively to a "how do I" question.  Sometimes a simple "how do I" question can actually benefit everyone when doing their  research when there are not dozens upon dozens of ways to accomplish the goal.

Comment: @psubsee2003 exactly what I was saying. Phrasing a question in a certain way does not necessarily make it broad. As I think is the case here where there likely is no actual possible way at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is exceptionally broad:

> Alternatively, is there some other more Chrome-like way to display warnings (imagine security issues)?

Questions like that is going to be closed quick for being too broad as there is a large amount of ways/services to achieve the same goal and can be also closed as off-topic for this reason:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: If it is really too broad because there are large amount of ways to achieve it, then can I please learn about at least one approach? Because I have not seen/found any working approach to do so. If you really think it is too broad, let's get answers. The only approach I have heard about are infobars which were deprecated. So no, I do not think it is too broad because there seems to be no way to do it.

Comment: Phrasing a question in a certain way does not necessarily make it broad. In  cases where the problem is likely impossible to accomplish phrasing is usually the same. What I'm trying to say is that one has to carefully consider the facts before stating that something is too broad.